# why void method can not be called in system.out.println

Tags: java

Can somebody please answer why this code is giving error?

```
package hello;

public class Hello {

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("eating");
    }

    private String run() {
    return "dwedsdfsdfsdf fsdf rgdsfG";

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println("Hello bhopi");
        //Hello hello = new Hello();
        Hello mahir = new Hello();
        //String y = mahir.eat();

        System.out.println(mahir.run());
        System.out.println(mahir.eat());
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the void method return?

Comment: Flagging - off topic - `why my code doesn't work` is a question seeking a  debugging support and should not be answered/asked.

Answer (score 1):

Because `void` method does not return anything, so there is nothing to print. The method `System.out.print()` expects an Object as a parameter to print.

Answer (score 1):

1) No method may accept as parameter an invocation to a `void` method.
It is like if you would pass a `void` argument to a method.

2) Here `println()` refers to the `PrintStream.println()` method as the `out` field is declared as `PrintStream`.
 To compile fine when you invoke it, you have to specify an argument that matches to one of the overloaded versions of this method.